# как активировать списки доступа для vlan

Tags: cisco

не видел смысла создавать для vlan-ов списки доступа для ограчения доступа к другим сетям, так как они и так не смогут передаться. а вот доступ к серверу нужен список доступа, не понимаю правда как активировать их потому что видимо в такой сети с транковым соединением это как работает по другому. в обычных сетях просто активировал к интерфейсу список доступа и все. а других отличий нет.
comp 1, 2, 3(11.1.0.2-4) ну или PC0,1,2 VLAN 10 11.1.0.1
comp 4, 5, 6 (12.1.0.2-4) ну или PC3,4,5 VLAN 11 12.1.0.1
comp 7, 8(13.1.0.3-4) ну или PC6, 7 VLAN 12 13.1.0.1
может мое транковое соединение неправильно настроено хотя хз, ну передача пакетов между своими vlan проходят.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Создайте acl и примените его на L3 свитче 3560. switch01 это L2 устройство, на нём вы можете ограничивать трафик между хостами в пределах vlan на основе mac адресов.